# Watch TV shows so that I can continue where I left off

Tags: windows-8, video, tv

I have several TV shows or series on my harddrive such that folder one contains all of the West Wing TV series and folder two contains all of the Simpsons TV shows and folder three contains all of the Dallas TV shows.

How can I watch them on a PC such that when I click on the last episode of West Wing (which I was watching) I can continue where I left off and when one episode finishes it moves to the next episode (of West Wing)?

Comment: Any decent player like VLC should support resuming playback. So just add all the files to your playlist, watch till you get tired, close it, and resume from where you left off next time.

Answer (score 3):

I know that product recommendations are off-topic here but you can use a media player such as [Kodi](http://kodi.tv/), formerly known as XBMC.

It has the exact features which you describe, and so many more.

Documented more in this thread: http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=138205

Comment: You are free to recommend products *in answers*. It's just that people shouldn't poll for them in questions. See also: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)

Answer (score -2):

This question is kind of a general question.

Usually you need to know the **file type** of your TV shows, a.k.a the **format**. If your Windows doesn't recognize these files you can see a short-term attached to the file name, separated from the name with a **dot**. That is the **extension** of the files. Go search for the extension on Google you will know what kind of file they are.

Then you will need a good **video player** that supports your required features. I haven't done researches on video players. Probably VLC Player may help a little but I am not sure if it supports continuing from where your stopped.

Comment: This answer is not really helpful. You say the OP needs a player that supports the features, but.. this is exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: so basically guys how do you watch multiple shows on pc in an organized manner. the tv shows (episodes) are in mp4 format.